# Class variable in Java

Tags: java

```
class C3 {
    public static int n = 0;
    public int m = 0;

    public C3() {
        n++; 
        m++; 
    }

    public void display() {
        System.out.println(n + " " + m);}
    }
}
```

Execution of: -

```
C3 c1 = new C3(); 
c1.display(); 
C3 c2 = new C3(); 
c1.display(); 
c2.display();
```

Prints numbers (output)

```
1 1 
2 1 
2 1
```

Can anyone please explain me the output step by step? i am a bit confused about the 2nd line of output, why didn't both m and n value increase? also in 3rd output why didn't it start from beginning?

Comment: If you go step by step through the code in your debugger you will be able to answer your own question. ;)

Answer (score 10):

`m` isn't static. That means that you have a different variable for each instance.

When you execute `new C3();`,

- you create a new instance of the class `C3`,
- you increment the static variable `n` (shared by all instances)
- you create a new variable `m`, initialized to `0`,
- and you increment `m` but only for your new instance.

Comment: Consider looking into an "object oriented Java tutorial".  I'm sure Google searching those words will come up with some.  These are important concepts to master for Java; simply understanding this one piece will not be sufficient for you.

Answer (score 3):

**n** is a `static variable`, thus all instances(c1 and c2 in this case) of the class share its data, where as **m** isn't a `static variable`, that means, each instance gets its own value of **m**

```
 //initial vals n=0 m=0;
  C3 c1 = new C3(); 
 //value of n is 1 value of m is 1   
 c1.display();


//initial values n=0, m=1(as c1 just incremented n which is static and c2 will now inc      n's current value(which is 1))    
C3 c2 = new C3(); 
//value of n is 2 value of m is 1 
c1.display(); 
c2.display();
```

Answer (score 1):

`n` is a static variable, as a result its scope is the class, not the instance.

`m`, on the other hand, is an instance variable and only has an existence within an instance.

As a result, each time you initialize a `new C3()`, `m` is set to 1 (since it is a new `m`), but `n` gets incremented each time (since all instances share it).

Answer (score 0):

For c1 and c2, only one n is available since n is static.But both will b ehaving separate m's since m is not static.

C3 c1 = new C3(); 
now m=1 and n=1 (m belongs to c1 and n belongs to class)
C3 c2 = new C3(); 
now m=1 and n=2 (m belongs to c1 and n belongs to class)

Comment: Everytime you create an object, same n is incremented.But in the case of m, each object will be having an indidual m which will be zero when object is created

Answer (score 0):

Every object you instantiate will have `m = 1` because m is an instance variable.
`n`, on the other hand, is a class variable. Every object you instantiate will increase the n by 1.

In your case, `n` will count how many objects you have created.

Answer (score 0):

```
class C3 {
public static int n = 0; //static or class variable, n does not become 0 after every new instance
public int m = 0; //instance variable, m becomes 0 for every instance

public C3() {
    n++; //n becomes the "last value the class had for n" + 1
    m++; //m becomes 1
}

public void display() {
    System.out.println(n + " " + m);}
}
```

}

Always look at a **static variable** as a **class variable**, so you will only instance it with 0 the **first time**.